# Alternating Colors of Rows with HTML

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

I am currently writing code in VBA to automate a process that sends out an e-mail that contains a table with information generated by a query in an Access database. I am using HTML to format the table in that e-mail, and I need the colors of the rows in that table to alternate colors (odd rows: #ccffcc; even rows: #ffffff), but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have tried to use the child selector, but I cannot see to figure out to get that to work in here. I do not have much experience or knowledge related to CSS or HTML, so I very well could have been using the child selector incorrectly.

Here is what I currently have:

```
Bodytext2 = "<html>" & _
    "<body>" & _
    "<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLpadding=0  style='font-family:Arial; font-size:12px'>" & _
    "<TBODY>" & _
    "<TH bgcolor='#dcdcdc'> Field1 </TH>" & _
    "<TH bgcolor='#dcdcdc'> Field2 </TH>" & _
    "<TH bgcolor='#dcdcdc'> Field3 </TH>"

'Creates the table
Set rst = mydb.OpenRecordset("Query In Access")
    Do Until rst.EOF
        Bodytext2 = Bodytext2 & _
        "<TR ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=MIDDLE>" & _
        "<TD> " & rst![Field1] & _
        "<TD> " & rst![Field2] & _
        "<TD> " & rst![Field3]
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst.Close

Bodytext2 = Bodytext2 & "</table>"
```

This code produces the correct table with the correct information. however, I am not sure where to add in the code to change the colors of the table's rows, or how to even write the code to do that. My guess so far is that it would be in the "TR Align=center valign=middle" portion, but that is just my guess.

I have looked a lot of other answers on here, but I think that my lack of knowledge in this field is making it difficult for me to determine what I actually need and where it needs to go. So, if there are helpful answers to similar questions that y'all could direct me to, I would greatly appreciate that too.

Thank You!

Comment: Please try: `<TR ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=MIDDLE style='background-color: #cccccc;'>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a counter variable before you go into your loop that will let you keep track of your row number, like this:

```
i = 1
Do Until rst.EOF
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Bodytext2 = Bodytext2 & "<TR ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=MIDDLE BGCOLOR='#ffffff'>"
    Else
        Bodytext2 = Bodytext2 & "<TR ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=MIDDLE BGCOLOR='#ccffcc'>"
    End If
    Bodytext2 = Bodytext2 & _
    "<TD> " & rst![Field1] & _
    "<TD> " & rst![Field2] & _
    "<TD> " & rst![Field3]
    rst.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

My apologies for any syntax errors.  My VBA is a little rusty.

Comment: By the way, I went ahead and did this in the HTML style you put forth, but you should know that that syntax is outdated.  The better, more standard way to do this would be:


`<tr style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background: #FFF">`

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much for both the initial answer and the updating of my code. I appreciate it!